# Python + Selenium -- Print out text

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium

In Selenium I want to print out a span element called:

```
<td class="Fw(b) Fz(s) Ta(end) Pb(20px)" data-reactid="60">
    <span data-reactid="61">23,849,000</span>
</td>
```

I need to print out "23,849,000".

I have tried this, but it doesn't seem to work:

```
print driver.find_element_by_xpath('''//*[@id="Col1-1-Financials-Proxy"]''').text
```

If you know a solution that might help, I would really appreciate your help as I don't know the answer.

Comment: There are no elements with `@id="Col1-1-Financials-Proxy"` on provided 
HTML sample... Can you share more HTML? Also clarify what do you mean by *it doesn't seem to work*

Comment: //*[@id="Col1-1-Financials-Proxy"]/section/div[3]/table/tbod‌​y/tr[4]/td[2]/span 
this is the xpath. And it doesn't even do anything with     print driver.find_element_by_xpath('''//*[@id="Col1-1-Financials-Proxy"]''').text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To print the span element as per the given `HTML` you can use the following line of code :

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
# code block
print(WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='Col1-1-Financials-Proxy']//td[@class='Fw(b) Fz(s) Ta(end) Pb(20px)']//following::span[1]"))).get_attribute("innerHTML"))
```

Answer (score 2):

Required value generated dynamically, so you need to wait until it appeared in DOM:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait as wait

print(wait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//span[@data-reactid='61']"))).text)
```

Comment: It says "invalid syntax" at reactid, when I run the program

Comment: Did you use my code exactly as it appears in answer? You can get "invalid syntax" only in case you modify it somehow...

Comment: I just made double-check. Copy-paste... and `'23,849,000'` as output... Maybe you replaced quotes? Single with double or wise-versa? share exact exception log

Comment: it just won't work for me for some reason. SyntaxSrror: invalid syntax

Comment: Syntax**S**rror ? With my code you made the same "copy and paste"? :)

Comment: Try to re-write code manually. It works and I see no reason for `invalid syntax` unless you've changed the code

Comment: Maybe I should make parenthesis after print? And how does your document look like, is it just those 4 lines? (:

Comment: If you use Python3.X, then you should use parenthesis. There is also `driver.get("https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/FB/financials?p=FB")` in my code

Answer (score 0):

try with :

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('.//div[@class="Fw(b) Fz(s) Ta(end) Pb(20px)"]')
```

You need to specify the correct path to reach the text inside span

Comment: This is the xpath: 
//*[@id="Col1-1-Financials-Proxy"]/section/div[3]/table/tbody/tr[4]/td[2]/span
And the website with the number I want to print is: https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/FB/financials?p=FB